# How to track page reload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Why does socket.io not handle page reload?

I have an express.js application, when reloading the page, `app.get('/')` is processed first and then `socket.on('disconnect')`. How do I handle disconnect socket first and then go to `app.get('/')` for the current page?

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('express get!')
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('socket disconnect!')
   })
})
```

**If you reload the page**

Console:

```sh
express get!
socket disconnect!
```

Expected behavior:

```sh
socket disconnect!
express get!
```

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? Why is it an issue that the `disconnect` event happens after the `.get`?

Comment: Can you add some code context please?

Comment: @ChrisG I want to understand whether the disconnect should be called after .get :)
because in my case disconnect is called after.

Comment: @JackBashford added!

Comment: `var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
` maybe try swap the order of these two binding order, and you'll see different behavior. I dono for sure. But it seems to me more like a impl detail.

Comment: How does path `/` is called when page reloads, is it the current page or you do this on a event handler

Comment: I assume it internally goes something like this: page reload -> browser sends get request -> express logs get request, sends reply -> browser receives reply and re-initializes window -> socket connection gets interrupted. Again: WHY do you want to handle the socket disconnect before the get request? Which problem are you trying to fix?

Comment: @Chris G, I need to perform some operation before the user requests app.get (). The user reloads the page, I in the disconnect handler execute some logic and then go to app.get (). It turns out that I can not perform this operation, because my disconnect is processed after the user requested the app.get

Comment: Sorry, but you aren't really telling me anything I don't already know about your issue. I'm fully aware *what* you want to do, what I'm asking is *why* you want to do it. What "operation" are we talking about? One way to address your issue is to run an ajax call to the express server after the client has established the socket connection, that way you can move the code from the regular `.get()` to the one handling the AJAX request. But it's still very possible that your question is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and I'm trying to get the necessary information.

Comment: @ChrisG, okay, thank you so much for spending time with me, i will try